# Django Commenting Errors

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and was working on my blog site to include a comment feature by using django-comments-xtd package.

I was following the tutorials specified on "https://django-comments-xtd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html", but it kept giving me an error saying
"DoesNotExist at /comments/post/" whenever I tried to submit any comment

This is comment section code from my blog template from DetailView:

```
{% if comment_count %}
    <hr/>
    <div class="comments">
        {% render_comment_list for object %}
    </div>
{% endif %}


<div class="card card-block mb-5">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title text-center pb-3">Post your comment</h4>
        {% render_comment_form for object %}
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my DetailView called PostDV:

```
class PostDV(DetailView):
    model = BlogModel
```

And this is the error which I am getting right now:

```
DoesNotExist at /comments/post/
Site matching query does not exist.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments/post/
Django Version: 3.1.6
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value: Site matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception (Site matching query does not exist.), another exception occurred:
comment = form.get_comment_object(site_id=get_current_site(request).id)
```

Does anybody had this kind of issue before?
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please [edit] and add the _full_ error traceback to your question.

Comment: Hello Joeng, You should upload your `full code ( models, urls, views )` and `full error traceback`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the second point in the [quickstart guide [django-comments-xtd Docs]](https://django-comments-xtd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) of the package you use:

> [Enable the “sites”
> framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework)
> by adding `'django.contrib.sites'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and defining
> `SITE_ID`. Visit the admin site and be sure that the domain field of
> the `Site` instance points to the correct domain (`localhost:8000`
> when running the default development server), as it will be used to
> create comment verification URLs, follow-up cancellations, etc.

You need to enable the sites framework, set the `SITE_ID` setting and make sure the domain is correctly saved. To do this as referred in Django's documentation (linked in above quote):

> 1. Add **'django.contrib.sites'** to your [**INSTALLED_APPS**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS)
>    setting.
> 2. Define a [**SITE_ID**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-SITE_ID)
>    setting:
>
>    ```
>     SITE_ID = 1
>    ```
> 3. Run [**migrate**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate).

After which go to the admin site and edit the Site object which would be created to have the correct domain for your server (In development `localhost:8000` or `127.0.0.1:8000`, etc., In production it depends on your site)

Comment: Thank you very much! Comments are now working properly!